# How to setup CSS for multiple font choices?

Tags: python, css, django

I want to build a website with Django and I need to create the CSS so that the user can have multiple choices when selecting a font. How do I setup this in CSS in a good way?

I have no idea where to start on this. I have only tried setting one font and created other themes with different fonts etc. This seems not like a good practice. Don't repeat yourself comes to mind :)

So what do I have to learn more about to be able to use multiple fonts so that the user can choose of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a css selector for each theme:

```css
.theme-time {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
.theme-courier {
    font-family: "courier";
}
.theme-verdana {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

2. Then, to give the ability to your user to change the theme and then the font-family, we will use Javascript. We will add one of this CSS class on the `html` or `body` tag.

**HTML part (with a select)** :

```html
<select id="theme-selector">
    <option value="theme-times">Times</option>
    <option value="theme-courier">Courier</option>
    <option value="theme-verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript part (with jQuery)** :

```js
// Detect when the value of the select change
$("#theme-selector").change(function() {
    // get the new theme name
    var theme = $(this).val();
    // We remove previous theme class
    // and add the new one
    $('body').removeClass((function (index, css) {
      return (css.match (/\s*theme-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass(theme);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to read the tutorials on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/).

In the example below, I've used multiple ways to set the `font-property`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#font-change").click(function() {
    $(".content").css("font-family", "Arial");
    $("#font-change").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  /* Set the font */
}
article {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
article:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
p.content {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #222;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Times;
  /* Set another font */
}
#font-change {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <h1>Article Title</h1>
  <h2 style="font-family:Helvetica;">Subtitle with a different font.</h2>
  <p class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tortor est, bibendum sit amet sapien eu, tempor pharetra nulla. Sed vel facilisis urna. Morbi euismod odio ut ullamcorper imperdiet. Donec imperdiet elit nec magna bibendum, mattis hendrerit
    leo pellentesque. Nunc ut massa tempus, dictum ex vel, laoreet neque. Vivamus vulputate diam risus, eu viverra odio fringilla ac. Aliquam convallis mi eu magna ultrices, eu placerat felis porta. Sed faucibus magna mi. Donec facilisis, justo at mollis
    rhoncus, lectus lectus tincidunt est, vitae elementum lectus mauris a nunc.
  </p>
  <button id="font-change">Change font</button>
</article>
```